# Beginner trying to program simple change calculator

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm new to coding and need to write a program for C# 
the goal is to write a program that prompts the user to enter an amount including decimals. and the program gives the user back the remander as money. ie...

quater dimes nickle pennie

Comment: So what you're saying is that you are taking a class and rather than put in the effort yourself to learn something new, you want complete strangers to do your homework for you.  Stack Overflow is not a homework service.  If you have a ***concrete*** question, then by all means please ask it.

Comment: Are you using windows forms? Console Application? @DavidL - I agree with david, this does sound like your homework. If it is that is fine we can hlep, but what have you tried. This sounds pretty beginner ish so I bet you cannot use classes. Have you learned how to create methods? How about static methods. I would make the method static personally that will be doing the work.

Comment: no what im saying is i have been writing this code for 4 hours and cntinue to get a debug error everytime i try to run the program. don't be a dick this is my 3rd day programming. im asking why when I concatenate with Parse  I get errors?

Comment: int dollar = 100;
            decimal quarter = .25m;
            decimal dime = .10m;
            decimal pennie = .01m;

            Console.WriteLine("tell me how much money you have, make sure you include doolars and cents. ");
            string userMoney = Console.ReadLine();
            int userMoney1 = int.Parse(userMoney);
            Console.WriteLine("that equals, " + userMoney1 / dollar / quarter / dime / pennie);

Comment: You arent the first one to have this assignment.  If you were to get your Google-Fu on you could probably find numerous good answers here.  Programming is an excercise in precision - *I get a debug error* is simply impossible to diagnose or help with.

Comment: Just posted an answer to your question. It's cool that you're getting into programming. You'll find out that research is a huge part of learning it. Keep that in mind. Just try to be as specific as possible with your questions, and before you even post a question do as much research as possible on your topic. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem isn't with your int.Parse, but with the way you were concatenating your Console.WriteLine string. Here's the fix, I'm not sure if that's what you were needing.

When you concatenate object to a string, add {}. Starting with the number 0 add those inside depending on how many object you want to add to the string like so: {0}. Once you're done with the string you can add the objects after the it separated by a comma.

```
int dollar = 100;
decimal quarter = .25m;
decimal dime = .10m;
decimal pennie = .01m;
Console.WriteLine("tell me how much money you have, make sure you include doolars and cents. ");
string userMoney = Console.ReadLine();

double userMoney1 = double.Parse(userMoney);
Console.WriteLine("that equals, {0} ", userMoney);

Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

First you want to get the users input and store it in a variable.

The input will be text so you have to convert that to a decimal.

Then you will need to do your calculations. That is probably the part you need help on.

Lets say the user entered in 25 dollars and 43 cents - 25.43.

I would first divide the dollars by 4 to get the number or quarters. 
Then go from there. You will likely use mod %.

Have fun, im sure you can figure it out if you try.

Comment: thank you Radmation

Comment: i wrote my division like this

Comment: int quarter = (int)(userAmount2 / .25m);